# Symfony2: How to replace a certain string with a global Twig variable?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the following in config.yml

```
twig:
    globals:
        locale_list_sg: Singapore
        locale_list_cn: China
```

In my twig template, I will like to get the values "Singpaore" and "China" based on a argument.
Therefore, I concatenate them like this and display:

```
{{'locale_list_' ~ countryId}}
```

However, the above will display locale_list_sg instead of going into config.yml and extract the values.

Comment: you shouldn't mix camelCase and under_score variable-names. Stick with one code-style. Twig by default uses underscore variable-names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a simpler approach:

**config.yml**

```
twig:
    globals:
        locale_list: 
            sg: Singapore
            cn: China
```

template:

```
{{ locale_list[country_id] }}
```

Comment: I like this answer. Just have a question, why there is a "-" before "sg" and "cn"?

Comment: It defines an array of [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Lists_of_associative_arrays) in YAML.

Comment: @nifr Wouldn't that be the equivalent of `- { sg: Singapore }` ? That would mean `locale_list[country_id]` would not work since the index would be `0` and not `sg`.

Comment: The question states that `{{ 'locale_list_' ~ countryId }}` resolves to `locale_list_sg` - meaning that `locale_list[country_id]` would resolve to `locale_list['sg']`. It's an associative array, so the keys arent integers but strings here. Or what's your question? numeric indexed arrays are of the form `[ 'value1', 'value2' ]` and associative ones are `{ 'key' : 'value' }`.

Comment: @AdamElsodaney is correct. Your Yaml ran through Symfony's Yaml parser returns this array: `Array ( [twig] => Array ( [globals] => Array ( [locale_list] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [sg] => Singapore ) [1] => Array ( [cn] => China ) ) ) ) )`

Comment: You're right @keyboardSmasher. I corrected the answer. The values were `- sg: Singapore` instead of `sg:  Singapore`. Thanks for your comment  :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware Twig will interpret strings as strings; it's not capable of determining variable variables... Its not pretty but a workaround (assuming you have a limited set of config options you don't mind retyping:

```
{{
    ('locale_list_' ~ countryId)|replace({
        'locale_list_sg': locale_list_sg,
        'locale_list_cn': locale_list_cn
    })
}}
```

Hope that helps.